# Why does data pass from ajax to a controller are always null

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm new in Laravel and I have tried to pass data from ajax using a post method.

my controller I tried to get the value, so  I used return response to show the result but it's always null.

here is my code :

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var tempsReal = 'matin';
        var dt = new Date($.now());
        var hs = dt.getHours();
        var d = new Date();
        d.setHours(12);
        if ((dt.getHours() >= d.getHours()))
            tempsReal = 'soir';
        $('#confirm').prepend('Marquer votre présence du : <strong>' + tempsReal + '</strong>');
        $(document).on('submit', '#frm', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        .
            $ajax({
                method: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: {tempsReal: tempsReal},
                //data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: "json"
            })
        });
    })
</script>
```

and I tryed this in my controller but it shows : **{"temps":null}**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->tempsReal = $request->input('tempsReal');

    return Response::json([
        'temps' => $this->tempsReal,
    ]);
}
```

and I also that one it shows always : **{"temps":null}**

```
public function store()
{
    $this->tempsReal = request()->get('tempsReal');

    return Response::json([
        'temps' => $this->tempsReal,
    ]);
}
```

Here is the form :

```
   <div class="container" id="RappelPres" style="
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 280px;
   left: 500px;
   border: 1px #a5a3a2 solid;">
   <div style="background-color: #42b43b;width:100%;height:40px;position: absolute ;left:0px">
       <form method="POST" action="{{ url('new') }}" style="text-align:center;"  role="form" id="frm" >
        {{ csrf_field()}}
        <button class="btn" id="confirm" type="submit" style="background-color:#42b43b;color: white;width:100%;height:100% "></button>
    </form>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<div class="container" style="width:98%">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible hidden">
        Pésence marqué avec succès.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible hidden" role="alert" style="width:98%">
</div>
</div>
```

I want to know where is the problem and how can I fix it!

Comment: Show your form too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the data sent through Ajax in the developer console and the method. If the method is 'GET' then since you are sending payload as JSON then laravel can't get 'tempsReal' from the request, If the request method is 'POST' and data sent contains { "tempsReal": "" } then output should contain the expected value.